# JSON Unrecognized character escape ':'

Tags: java, json, parsing, exception

Good day,

I am doing the `POST` of json property as follows:

```
{"db.URL":"jdbc\:derby\:C\:\\Users\\Sasha\\unicentaopos-database;create\=true"}
```

And getting an exception: `Unrecognized character escape ':' (code 58)\n at [Source: java.io.StringReader@358b85c8; line: 1, column: 480]`

Now, I guess I need to replace `\` with `\\`, but whenever I do that:

```
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
```

I get another exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1702)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
    at com.openbravo.pos.forms.AppConfig.convertConfigToJson(AppConfig.java:332)
    at com.openbravo.pos.forms.AppConfig.load(AppConfig.java:221)
    at com.openbravo.pos.forms.AppConfig.init(AppConfig.java:141)
    at com.openbravo.pos.forms.AppConfig.<init>(AppConfig.java:70)
    at com.openbravo.pos.forms.AppConfig.GetAppConfig(AppConfig.java:78)
    at com.openbravo.pos.forms.StartPOS$1.run(StartPOS.java:99)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

How do I deal with it?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not too familiar with this, but should you be escaping the colon or the equals?

Comment: I think it is complaining about the single back slash before the colon therefore needs to be replaced with double back slash not to escape the colon because you shouldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) files you must escape `=` and `:` but in raw Java you do not need to.

The correct escaping (I believe) should be:

```
"jdbc:derby:C:\\Users\\Sasha\\unicentaopos-database;create=true"
```

i.e. You only need to esacpe a `\` (and `"` if there are any).

Comment: BTW - It is unlikely that `jdbc:derby:C:\\` is what you meant. Starting with `jdbc` means that it is a database connection. Finding `C:\` in a database connection string is very unlikely.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do here: jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\"); But getting an Exception

Comment: It's not related to the question, more over I am reading an existing file that is ALREADY used by the system.

Comment: @Sasha - No it is not. The original string is wrongly escaped already, even before you do your `replaceAll`.

Comment: @Sasha - *I am reading an existing file* - Would that be a `properties` file? If so you must either reverse the escaping in it or read it **as a properties file**.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon unless he uses the embedded version of derby, check this https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/devguide/rdevdvlp22102.html especially the example jdbc:derby:/reference/phrases/french

Comment: Yes it is properties file, please suggest how you do that?

Comment: @Sasha - After reading from properties file you should replace `\:` and `\=` with `:` and `=`. Something like `jsonString.replaceAll("\\:", ":").replaceAll("\\=","=")`.